# How do I align the text below a little better?

Tags: math-mode

I almost always use

```
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split} 
your equation here // equation in next line
\end{split} 
\end{equation}
```

and I get a really bad aligning in which the text is going outside the border on the right. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Could you please add an example? Btw, it should be `your equation here \\ equation in next line` instead of `your equation here // equation in next line`.

Comment: `split` is intended to use wit ampersands which determine where equation should be aligned. as far i understood your question, try to replace `split` with `gathered`.

Comment: Would you please add the code for the big display so that we can play with it and perhaps suggest something to get a better appearance?

Comment: @egreg I will do it the moment I have access to my computer .

Comment: When you are getting squeezed for space this badly, there aren't a lot of options.  First, you cold move the equation number to the last line using align and \notag instead of equation and split.  You should align the equstions using &= and, if not enough room, split of part off the equation using &\quad+ (for example).

Answer (score 4):

if i correctly understood your question you looking for alignment showed in the second equation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{your equation here} \\ 
\text{equation in the next line}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\text{your equation here} \\
\text{equation in the next line}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

if i understood you correctly than your use of `split` is wrong. it is intended for use in cases similar to the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
y & = \text{your equation here} \\      % observe ampersands
  & = \text{equation in the next line}  % <---
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]